# How to access to a cell into a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Issue trying to get a value from a DataFrame

I'm using pyspark in Databricks, I'm trying to get the amount of rows as a value to do some calculation

What I did:

```
f=sqlContext.sql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTF FROM SOOMLA')
#It´s a dataframe
```

Now I want to get this number into the DataFrame as a value to make calculation, I tried already:

```
f['COUNTF'].iloc[0]
```

but I got:

```
Out[158]: Column<b'COUNTF[iloc][0]'>
```

How can I get this 439016392 as a value?

Comment: I think you want to do `val = sqlContext.sql('SELECT * FROM SOOMLA').count()` and then val should be your integer with the number of rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store aggregate value of a PySpark dataframe column into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987454/store-aggregate-value-of-a-pyspark-dataframe-column-into-a-variable) and also maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594176/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-rows-of-a-dataframe-efficiently).

Comment: @Alejandro you *could* also [convert to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826553/convert-between-spark-sql-dataframe-and-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1): `f.toPandas()['COUNTF'].iloc[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're mixing Pandas df with Spark df when using `iloc`.

```
type(f['COUNTF'])

pyspark.sql.column.Column
```

You can do it, as Ben T suggested by:

```
f=sqlContext.sql('SELECT * FROM SOOMLA').count()
print(f)
```

or convert the df to `pandas` first and then:

```
f=sqlContext.sql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTF FROM SOOMLA').toPandas()['COUNTF'].iloc[0]
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `collect()` and extract the first item into a variables. Here is example:

```
f = sqlContext.sql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTF FROM SOOMLA').collect()[0][0]

print(f)
#3

type(f)
#int
```

`collect()` returns list of Rows.  So `collect()[0]` will return first row from list and `collect()[0][0]` will return first element of first row from list.

Here we are running `COUNT(*)` and it will return one record/row. So in this case `collect()` is returning one list with one row only and we need to extract first element from first row so `collect()[0][0]` will work.

I hope this explanation helps!